# How to show variable length text in fixed width textbox in jquery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In jQuery dialog there is textbox containing variable length text ... 
I want to textview to adjust it's width within Dialog box (Scroller is displayed if textbox exceeds width of dialog and I don't want that scroller)..
Text should be adjusted within textbox (there should not be any scroller) (Height problem)...

Comment: could you give us some of your source or a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers your question: 
[Automatically resize jQuery UI dialog to the width of the content loaded by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231446/automatically-resize-jquery-ui-dialog-to-the-width-of-the-content-loaded-by-ajax#2262382)

```
$(".mydialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width:'auto'
});
```