# How to resize jquery ui dialog with browser

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

I open jquery ui dialog and load some content in it. But when I resize browser jq dialog doesn't change it's width/height. I have tried a few thing but no luck. Here how I open it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
            var dWidth = wWidth * 0.9;
            var wHeight = $(window).height();
            var dHeight = wHeight * 0.9;

            $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        show: 'fade',
                        width: dWidth,
                        height: dHeight,                    
                        create: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("display", "none");

                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 0);
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border", 0);
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding", 0);

                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("background", "#000000");
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("overflow", "hidden");

                        }  

                    })
                    .load(this.href);
            });
$(window).resize(function () {
            var wWidth = $(window).width();
            var dWidth = wWidth * 0.9;
            var wHeight = $(window).height();
            var dHeight = wHeight * 0.9;
            $(".openDialog").dialog("option", "width", dWidth);
            $(".openDialog").dialog("option", "height", dHeight);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After the dialog has been opened the width and height are static unless resized. Bind an event to the window resize that will change it instead.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    var dWidth = wWidth * 0.9;
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var dHeight = wHeight * 0.9;
    $("#data-dialog-id").dialog("option", "width", dWidth);
    $("#data-dialog-id").dialog("option", "height", dHeight);
});
```

Comment: I put whole my function for loading ui dialog in resize function that you provided. And I get dialog resized on browser resize but then I ui dialog is not modal it's displayed as a page and I get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
(anonymous function)

Comment: I would leave them as two separate functions.  That way the resize isn't messing with the dialog's init.  Just put the window resize function after your code in the document ready function.

Comment: I have updated question. I must do something wrong because it doesn't resize :(

Comment: I updated the function above. the dialog was actually attached to a new div element you are creating not openDialog. I should have read a little closer. Whatever you end up calling that new div is what you need in the resize function.

Comment: Wired I debug this function it gets value on resize but dialog stay the same :/

Comment: And when I set width/height to 'auto' it resize good but dialog is not centered anymore...

Comment: You should also add the following line to ensure the dialog stays in the center of the screen:

$("#data-dialog-id").dialog("option", "position", "center");

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you trigger the event resize off the dialog it should do it.

$( ".selector" ).dialog( "resize");

Comment: That doesn't work. "Uncaught Error: no such method 'resize' for dialog widget instance"

Answer (score 0):

It appears @jasonday has a nice script that amends the JQuery UI dialog functionality - seems to be working *fairly* well for me.

[Here's his SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509762/1520850)

[Here's his script on github: jQuery-UI-Dialog-extended](https://github.com/jasonday/jQuery-UI-Dialog-extended)